# How to stub_command in ChefSpec?

Tags: ruby, rspec, chef-infra, chefspec

I have this condition in my recipe:

```rb
install_action = (::Win32::Service.exists?(windows_service['name']) ? :configure : :create)
```

and a ChefSpec for that in spec file:

```rb
#1: not working 
allow_any_instance_of(Win32::Service)
                .to receive(:exists?)
                .with(windows_service[:name])
                .and_return(true)
#2: also not working
stub_command("::Win32::Service.exists?(#{windows_service[:name]})").and_return(true)
```

Could you please help to find out what have I missed in the ChefSpec test that is not working and mocking the return value.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
allow(::Win32::Service).to receive(:exists?).with(windows_service[:name]).and_return(true)
```

Point is you stub a class method `exists?`, and not an instance method. That's why `allow_any_instance_of` does not work. And `stub_command` is actually for shell commands like `stub_command('cat file | grep "hello"')`